# Need to show parallel all cells of a row in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to have a table that has some `<td>` in it and and in this table I have labels that gets data from database and they change in length each time the data bind to it is different the problem is the alignment of these labels in the '' changes too here is a example of what I have.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style4"><span style="padding-right:100px">  </span>Full Name:

   <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>   <span style="padding-right:400px;width:400px;"></span> Address:
      <asp:Label ID="lblTuition" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks spacing in between I am using `<span>` to give spacing in between them and now when lets say the FullName have a value that's a big value the Address: gets pushed away further is there a way I could have any value but the spacing for these 2 don't change and I don't want to use the float-right for address I want these to be kind of in the middle of the table

Expected result could be some thing like this:

[image: This is the pdf image of how it should look like]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by breaking your name and address headers up into two separate cells. That will allow you to specify how far apart you want the cells to be, regardless of the length of the data being imported:

```css
td {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style4">
      </asp:Label>Full Name:
      <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="">
    </td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
      </asp:Label>Address:
      <asp:Label ID="lblTuition" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```